# Cucumber scenario errors when optional parameter isn't included in step

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd

I have this step definition in my Cucumber application:

```
@Then("Client {string} just received {int} {string}")
@Then("Client {string} just received {int} messages, a {string} and a {string}")
public void clientJustReceivedRequestReject(String session, int numMessages, String message, String... additionalMessages) throws InterruptedException{
    receiver = new TcpClientReceiver(socketMap.get(session),properties,sessionsList.stream().filter(s->s.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(session)).findFirst().get(), new GlobalStatistics());
    List<String> messagesList=new ArrayList<>();
    messagesList.add(message);
    if (additionalMessages.length > 0) {
        Arrays.stream(additionalMessages).forEach(messagesList::add);
    }
    List<Message> messages=receiver.scanForMutlipleMessages(messagesList,"35");
    assertTrue(messages.size()==numMessages);
```

When I run a scenario with step, `Then Client "PC1" just received 2 messages, a "RequestReject" and a "AdminHeartbeat"` the test passes without issue. However, if I run a scenario with step `Then Client "PC1" just received 1 "RequestReject` I get the below error:

> io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Step [Client {string} just received {int} {string}] is defined with 4 parameters at 'com.me.ed.testtool.StepDef.clientJustReceivedRequestReject(java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)'.
> However, the gherkin step has 3 arguments:
>
> - "PC1"
> - 1
> - "RequestReject"
>   Step text: Client "PC1" just received 1 "RequestReject"
>   at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.arityMismatch(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:83)
>   at io.cucumber.core.runner.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:42)
>   at io.cucumber.core.runner.ExecutionMode$1.execute(ExecutionMode.java:10)
>   at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:92)
>   at io.cucumber.core.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:64)
>   ...

How can I resolve this so I can have a step which doesn't contain the optional parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Java does not have optional parameters. What Java does have are varargs. They're kinda like optional parameters, but not quite.

So you have to create two methods instead. If you use a data table it will be easier to accept a variable number of messages.

```
Then Client "PC1" just received a "RequestReject"
Then Client "PC1" just received 2 messages:
  | RequestReject  |
  | AdminHeartbeat |
```

```java
@Then("Client {string} just received a {string}")
public void clientJustReceived(String session, int numMessages, String message) {
    clientJustReceivedRequestReject(session, 1, Collections.singletonList(message));
}

@Then("Client {string} just received {int} messages:")
public void clientJustReceived(String session, int numMessages, List<String> messages) {

}
```